# Cypress if compare object

Tags: javascript, cypress

(.pd-incidents-table tbody) have random elements;
I need to check every details-cell of each element of (.pd-incidents-table tbody);
Its working fine, but I need to do something if the assertion match/fail

ex:
if details-cell element[3]  match with "BOXER123", need to click on something
else do nothing

Current behaviour is: Even if match or fail the cy.get(btn).click() dont execute

```
   let found = false
   const timeout = 11 
   for(let i = 1; i<timeout && !found ;i++){
    cy.get(`.pd-incidents-table tbody >`).each((el, index) => {
      cy.get(`.pd-incidents-table > table > tbody > :nth-child(${index+1}) .details-cell`).invoke('text').then( text => {
         if(softExpect(text).to.contains('BOXER123')){
           cy.get(btn).click()
          }
```

Comment: Can you do a `cy.log()` inside the if statement to check whether the control goes inside the if block ?

Comment: Please show how `btn` is set, what is the selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Even if match or fail the `cy.get(btn).click()` does not execute*** - this is probably a problem with `btn`.

The first thing to do is to simplify and remove all the nesting.

***else do nothing*** - means you don't need an `if`, just select the matching elements and do the click.

### Multiple cells have text

```js
// Look for cells containing "BOXER123"
const cellSelector = '.pd-incidents-table td.details-cell:contains("BOXER123")';

cy.get(cellSelector).each(cell => {
  cy.wrap(cell).find('button').click();   // wrap + find gets just the button in the cell
});
```

Data is random, so if you have a situation where the ***may not be*** cells with the text and you don't want to fail the test, then

```js
// Look for cells containing "BOXER123"
const cellSelector = '.pd-incidents-table td.details-cell:contains("BOXER123")';

if (Cypress.$(cellSelector).length) {     // check that any cells exist

  cy.get(cellSelector).each(cell => {
    cy.wrap(cell).find('button').click(); // wrap + find gets just the button in the cell
  });

}
```

---

### Single cell has text

I you only want the ***first*** cell with text "BOXER123", then it can be simpler

See [contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Yields)

> .contains() yields the new DOM element it found

```js
// Look for cells containing "BOXER123"
const cellSelector = '.pd-incidents-table td.details-cell';

cy.contains(cellSelector, 'BOXER123').within(cell => {  // within the cell
  cy.get('button').click(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1.Using [cy.contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax). It gets the DOM element containing the text. Assuming that *BOXER123* is a unique text in your table.

```
let found = false
const timeout = 11
for (let i = 1; i < timeout && !found; i++) {
  cy.get(`.pd-incidents-table tbody >`).each((el, index) => {
    cy.get(`.pd-incidents-table > table > tbody > :nth-child(${index+1}) .details-cell`).invoke('text').then(text => {
      if (softExpect(text).to.contains('BOXER123')) {
        cy.contains(text).click()
      }
    })
  })
}
```

2.Using [cy.wrap()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html#Syntax). It yields the object passed into `.wrap()`. If the object is a promise, yield its resolved value.

```
let found = false
const timeout = 11
for (let i = 1; i < timeout && !found; i++) {
  cy.get(`.pd-incidents-table tbody >`).each((el, index) => {
    cy.get(`.pd-incidents-table > table > tbody > :nth-child(${index+1}) .details-cell`).then($ele => {
      if ($ele.text().trim() == 'BOXER123') {
        cy.wrap($ele).click()
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: @eric99 True, since the OP is checking the presence of text using the if condition, I assumed that the text is occurring once in the table. I have anyways added this to the answer, that the text must be uniqe.

Comment: Yes, it is rather hard to tell what his intention is - for example, what is the purpose of `timeout` and `found`? I guess those indicate that only the ***first*** cell is required (although he never sets `found`).